# C + WINAPI: How To handle Files?

Tags: c, winapi, file-handling

OK, I have read about CreateFile, ReadFile and WriteFile and I know how to use these. But I could not find any tutorial or guide with an example to use them properly.
How do I handle files?
I want to learn about:

1. Read strings from file.
2. Write strings to file.

How does one do that?

Comment: Careful! These function read and write bytes, not strings. You'll have to do the conversion. This might be a good time to read up on Unicode, UTF-16 and UTF-8 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/platform-specific/windows/file-io-in-visual-c-r707

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder where it was when I was searching. You just saved lot of time for me! :)